# Vue.js component updates inconsistently

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm just experimenting with Vue.js and have encountered what seems to be inconsistent behavior by Vue.js updating a component. (The commented out <span> triggers the behavior I expect.)

The problem is that clicking the button updates the button text but doesn't cause the component text to be updated ("updated" should increment as well). It lags the button count by one. (Using vue devtools in a browser shows that the data is changed but doesn't update the DOM.)

Here is a jsfiddle: [increment problem](https://jsfiddle.net/bmacnaughton/nojvp3dn/) and the code is below.

Now uncomment the <span> block by adding --> to the first <-- line and the updates now work as expected in the <span> and the component. Here is the jsfiddle with the section uncommented: [increment works](https://jsfiddle.net/bmacnaughton/nojvp3dn/9/).

Why does the component updating change?

HTML:

```
<div id="app">

<!--
<span
    v-for='(count, state) in stateChanges'>
    {{state}}: {{count}} 
</span><br/>
<!-- -->

<state-changes
    :states='["created", "mounted", "updated"]'
    :counters='stateChanges'>
</state-changes>

<button v-on:click="doCount"> {{count}}</button>    
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
Vue.component('state-changes', {
    props: ['states', 'counters'],
    template: `<p><span v-for="state in states">{{state}}: {{counters[state]}} </span></p>`,
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        stateChanges: {
            created: 0,
            mounted: 0,
            updated: 0,
            destroyed: 0
        },
        count: 0,
    },
    methods: {
        doCount() {
            this.count += 1;
        },
    },
    created() {this.stateChanges.created++},
    mounted() {this.stateChanges.mounted++},
    updated() {
        this.stateChanges.updated++
        },
    destroyed() {this.stateChanges.destroyed++},
});
```

Comment: You're in uncharted territory here. The [official docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated) recommends against changing state in `updated`, since it should generally update infinitely (which makes sense). If you try the same code with `beforeUpdate` instead of `updated`, you'll actually get the expected infinite loop and a warning about it in the console.

So while it's true that the behaviour is inconsistent (and probably worthy of a bug report) you're doing things incorrectly as is. I recommend you state your specific problem directly so we can help you find a better way to solve it.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware of the recommendation against changing state in updated. I had thought about the infinite loop and presumed they detected circular references and just broke the loop. This was just an insight tool for me as I worked to familiarize myself with Vue.js, so I don't have a specific need to show the update count.